# Getting errors in tsconfig.json after adding Tailwindcss v3 to Nextjs (create-next-app --typescipt)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js, tailwind-css

Here is the error in VS code

```
Cannot find type definition file for 'accepts'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'accepts'
```

I have tried installing types for 'accepts' using "yarn add @types/accepts" but then it shows the same error for "body-parser" and keeps going on and on and telling me to add types for different packages which are unknown to me.

Package Versions:

```
"next": "^12.0.8"
"tailwindcss": "^3.0.15",
"postcss": "^8.4.5",
"autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
"typescript": "^4.5.5"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was this error when run `next build` and the types of tailwindcss don't found! Inside my folder `node_modules/@types/tailwindcss` don't had any file `.d.ts` an another folders existed files `index.d.ts` that had rules of types... I just removed dependencies of `@types/tailwindcss` and worked, try this too!

If you need files of types, try create an custom file `.d.ts`